# How to draw circle in basemap or add artiste

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I want to know how can i plot a circle with Basemap using latitude and longitude.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis([0,10,0,10])
circle1 = plt.Circle((5, 5), 2, color='black',fill=False)
x = ax.add_artist(circle1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to do the same but with x,y,radius as lon lat in my basemap graph

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection="mill", #miller est une projection connu
    llcrnrlat =0,#lower left corner latitude
    llcrnrlon =0,
    urcrnrlat =10, #upper right lat
    urcrnrlon =10,
    resolution = "l") #c croud par defaut, l low , h high , f full 
m.drawcoastlines() #dessiner les lignes
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcounties(color="b")
#m.fillcontinents() #colorier les payes
#m.etopo()

x,y=m(5,5)
m.plot(x,y,"o")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I guess you forgot to state the actual problem. There is no circle in the second code, hence it will not appear in the graph.

Comment: My problem is i don't know how to add a circle in the second graph, with (5,5) as center and 2 as radius.

Comment: Well that might be a problem, but as long as you don't try it, this problem does not become apparent.

Comment: I didn't get it, i want to plot both circle and map in same graph is it possible? :/

Comment: I guess so. At the moment I don't even see the problem in doing so, you have the code that does it, just paste it into the other code, see what happens, repair some of the namings etc. And then tell us at which point it breaks.

Comment: Well that's my question... i don't know how to add circle in Basemap, `AttributeError: 'Basemap' object has no attribute 'add_artist'
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the two codes ready you can just copy the one into the other. The only problem may be that the circle radius needs to be calculated in map coordinates,

```
r = 2
x,y=m(5,5)
x2,y2 = m(5,5+r) 
circle1 = plt.Circle((x, y), y2-y, ..)
```

Complete example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

m = Basemap(projection="mill", #miller est une projection connu
    llcrnrlat =0,#lower left corner latitude
    llcrnrlon =0,
    urcrnrlat =10, #upper right lat
    urcrnrlon =10,
    resolution = "l", ax=ax) #c croud par defaut, l low , h high , f full 
m.drawcoastlines() #dessiner les lignes
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcounties(color="b")

x,y=m(5,5)
x2,y2 = m(5,5+2) 
circle1 = plt.Circle((x, y), y2-y, color='black',fill=False)
ax.add_patch(circle1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea on how to adpt this to Cartopy?

Comment: @ouranos This question is about basemap. If you have a question about Cartopy you can ask it, using the respective tag.

Comment: Does this actually draw the circle in map coordinates or just place a perfect circle centered via map coordinates with a radius defined in map coordinates? If I do this at high latitudes in an ortho projection for example, the circle doesn't distort which seems odd to me.

Comment: @Will.Evo No, the center and radius are in map coordinates (specifically, the radius is in y-coordinates of the map). This works well for zoomed-in regions. But the circle's circumference has absolutely no meaning in geographic coordinates, it's just a circle on the map (as if you take a pen and draw a circle in your atlas).

Answer (score 2):

So I'm not sure the radius that you want your circle in your map, but this code will draw you a circle polygon on top of your map `m`:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

m = Basemap(projection="mill", #miller est une projection connu
    llcrnrlat =0,#lower left corner latitude
    llcrnrlon =0,
    urcrnrlat =10, #upper right lat
    urcrnrlon =10,
    resolution = "l") #c croud par defaut, l low , h high , f full
```

For the circle here, I just arbitrarily chose a radius of 1/3 the entire length of your y-axis...

```
circle = Circle(xy=m(5,5),radius=(m.ymax - m.ymin) / 3, fill=False)
plt.gca().add_patch(circle)

m.drawcoastlines() #dessiner les lignes
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea on how to adpt this to Cartopy?